# JHipster Nginx HTTPS This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources

Tags: nginx, https, jhipster

To make my story short, here is shown error message(in chromium console):

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/#/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://example.com/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

And you see this message if you click the security icon(in chromium address bar):
[image: Chrome security alert]

To investigate this further I notice, on page load event, we do have a request to `/api/account` secure end-point and since first-time visitors are not usually authenticated, then this request will get redirected to `/login` path (in somewhere?). but over HTTP and not HTTPS, which will be desire behaviour in my case.

I'm suspicious that this is because I do use my JHipster application behind a reverse proxy and my reverse proxy is responsible for serving requests over HTTPS. In another words my JHipster application doesn't know that we are using HTTPS.

I also did try to debug my client-side code to see if I could override this behaviour but I notice this redirect is not triggered from neither `auth-expired.interceptor.ts` or `errorhandler.interceptor.ts`.

So more likely this redirect is happening form my server-side code and maybe could be override by changing an spring security config?

Thank you JHipsters! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `server.use-forward-headers: true` in your `application.yml`.  Make sure your proxy server is also configured to add `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers.  For Nginx, you can add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` in the `location` section.  This will fix your 302 redirects which are built from the proxy headers.

This is described in the Spring Boot [docs for running behind a proxy server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server), also there was a related [Github issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7405).

Comment: Thanks Jon! this solved my issue, plus `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` must be present in `location` section of Nginx configuration for this to work as expected. I also found `application-prod.yml` a better place to set `server.use-forward-headers: true`. since I don't use Nginx in development mode. Cheers! p.s. I did reach 5 time limit for editing previous comment, so I delete it and rewrite this one. I keep press enter for going to next line! :-)