# Incorrect redirect_url in JHipster social login

Tags: nginx, oauth, oauth-2.0, jhipster

Google social login works on localhost, for example, `localhost:8888/portal`,

still on a production system where the host is `domain.com/portal`,

the **redirect_url is** incorrect `domain:8888/portal`,

**not** `domain.com/portal`

The production application is behind nginx proxy in docker:

```
location /portal {
   proxy_pass http://domain:8888;
}
```

Incorrect requequest by `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?clie...`

```
client_id=...
response_type=code
_csrf=
redirect_uri=http://domain:8888/portal/signin/google
scope=...
state=
```

Comment: Have you configured your app for running behind nginx?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49867166/3737815

Comment: Still the same. 

A couple of new findings. Same with FB social login. 
domain.com/portal/signin/facebook does not send any payload containing the port number value, still in response, I can see incorrect redirect URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in nginx reverse proxy configuration:

Before (with the issue)

```
  location /portal {
        proxy_pass http://site:8888;

        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

After (fixed the issue)

```
location /portal {
        proxy_pass http://site:8888;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $scheme;
    }
```